# Difference/Equality of com.sun.faces > jsf-impl and org.glassfish > javax.faces (2.2.4)

Tags: maven, jsf-2

In my JSF2 application I have faced a NPE in Primefaces (5.1) autocomplete at

`org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer
 .encodeSuggestionsAsList(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:492)`

I have solved my problem by replacing the maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

by

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

This is confusing me.

Searching for the projects homepages I found these maven repositories:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.4
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.4

They both claim the same description and reference the same URL as Homepage:

Description: Oracle's Implementation Of The JSF 2.2 Specification (2.2.4)
  HomePage: http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/

**Can someone explain the difference? Shouldn't the be exactly the same?**

Hint: I know about the history of sun and Oracle. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`com.sun.faces:jsf-impl`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.4) contains only the implementation (Mojarra). It lacks the API. You'd need a [`com.sun.faces:jsf-api`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.2.4) along it.

The [`org.glassfish:javax.faces`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.4) is the single-JAR bundle containing both API and impl (you can also see it at the file size).

As to your concrete problem when using only the `jsf-impl`, apparently you forgot the `jsf-api`, or you relied on [`javax:javaee-web-api`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-web-api/7.0) while actually using a non-Java EE container like Tomcat.

Comment: I am using tomcat 8.0.15 and JDK 1.8.0_25. `jsf-api` was part of the dependencies all the time. But I didn't know that `org.glassfish:javax.faces` is a bundle. Now I will remove jsf-api. But the application was working except the autocomplete part, and shouldn't the implementations exactly be the same?

Comment: But `javax:javaee-api 7.0` is part of my dependencies.

Comment: Tomcat is not a Java EE container. It's a barebones JSP/Servlet container. If you want a Java EE container, go for TomEE or WildFly.

Comment: Seems to be a very specific combination of `javax:javaee-api`,`com.sun.faces:jsf-api` and `com.sun.faces:jsf-impl` in my project (and tomcat) that's not working. Using these dependencies autocomplete throws NPE in `AutoCompleteRenderer.java:492`. Without `javaee-api` at all I can use `jsf-api`/`jsf-impl`, **or** `org.glassfish:javax.faces`.

Comment: Indeed. The `javaee-web-api` doesn't contain code attributes, it only contains class/method signatures. This is usually already provided by the Java EE container. However Tomcat isn't such one. You'd need to provide the actual APIs such as `jsf-api` individually. As answered :)

Comment: @BalusC my question here is why should i use org.glassfish:javax.faces jar instead of using both com.sun.faces:jsf-api and com.sun.faces:jsf-impl jars together ? is there's any difference ?

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh: If it's the same version then no, there's no difference. But the separated api/impl JARs are not available anymore since Mojarra 2.3.x. So you would be out of date if you're using only api/impl.